# UIDocumentMenuViewController gets crash

Tags: ios, xcode, uidocumentmenuvc

I'm using **Document Menu** in my app, if I try to choose particular provider from Document Menu list e.g. Dropbox component gets crash.

crash log:

```
plugin com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default invalidated
```

I couldn't find any solution for my problem...
There were couple topics which I have found but no one fits into my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found problem I loses reference to object which holds documentMenuView.